# HTML5 insert data to input field

Tags: html, input, local-storage

I am developing an appin phonegap.. where a recall button is there in a page when an user press recall button the data will be stored in local storage and that data needs to enter in the appropriate inputfields... but I am not getting the data in input fields ..I am giving my code below.. if any error pls help..

```
<body onload="onLoad();">    
<div class="app">
<form>
* First name:<br>
<input type="text" style="width:80%;" id="fn" input name="first" maxlength="15">
<br>
</form>   
</div>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function onLoad() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('name1') == "roy")
{
document.getElementById("fn").value=localStorage.getItem('fnm');
}
}        
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in js console? jsfiddle works fine with your code. Maybe `if` is not working. Try to add debug logging into `onLoad` function

Answer (score 0):

Try setting and getting localstorage values using `JSON` methods like shown below.

Setting value:
`localStorage.getItem('KEY',JSON.stringify('VALUE'))`

Getting the Value:
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fnm'))`